# Very basic DependencyProperty problem in WPF - tyring to bind to a complex object

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm just getting started with WPF.
I have TextBox declared in xmal like so:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=TestComplex.Something, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In my code behind I have registered the property that I am trying to bind to like so:

```
public TestComplexObject TestComplex
    {
        get { return (TestComplexObject)GetValue(TestComplexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestComplexProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestComplexProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestComplex", typeof(TestComplexObject ), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(new TestComplexObject ()));
```

The TestComplexObject class:

```
public class TestComplexObject : DependencyObject 
{
    public string Something
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomethingProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(ExeLocationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomethingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Something", typeof(string), typeof(TestComplexObject), new UIPropertyMetadata("Test Text"));

}
```

As you can see I'm trying to bind the TextBox to TestComplex.Something, however when I run this all I get is a xmal parse exception,

> "'The invocation of the constructor on
>   type 'EmuRunner.MainWindow' that
>   matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.' Line
>   number '6' and line position '9"

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look in the exception's InnerException property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will find that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168648/why-would-a-dependency-property-implementation-crash-my-application-when-i-provid) contains the answer to your problem.

Basically, your `TestComplexObject` isn't free threaded and thread safe (e.g. derived from System.Windows.Freezable).  Type initializers for the two types (`MainWindow` and `TestComplexObject`) are (or could be) running simultaneously on different threads - which would cause a cross-threading exception (or worse) when the type initializer for `MainWindow` causes the type initializer for `TestComplexObject` to be called.  The framework detects this potential and throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I'll check when I get home but that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
set { SetValue(ExeLocationProperty, value); }
```

You are only allowed to call `SetValue(SomethingProperty, value);`  in a setter for `Something`.

Comment: That's not true.  There's no required relationship between the names of dependency properties and the names of the CLR properties they're exposed as.  That the CLR property `Foo` maps to the dependency property `FooProperty` is entirely a convention.  In fact you can have multiple CLR properties that all set the same DP.  A terrible, terrible idea, but it won't throw an exception.